# Циклы, работа с массивами объектами?

Tags: javascript

```js
var auto = [
          {
            marka: "BMW",
            model: "4k",
            cuzov: "A";
          }
           {
            marka: "Merc",
            model: "4k",
            cuzov: "B";
          }
           {
            marka: "Audi",
            model: "3k",
            cuzov: "C";
          }
           {
            marka: "Toyota",
            model: "1k",
            cuzov: "D";
          }
           {
            marka: "Lexus",
            model: "2k",
            cuzov: "E";
          }
           {
            marka: "Rang",
            model: "3k",
            cuzov: "F";
          }
           {
            marka: "BMW",
            model: "4k",
            cuzov: "G";
          }
           {
            marka: "BMW",
            model: "2k",
            cuzov: "Y";

          }
           {
            marka: "Audi",
            model: "3k",
            cuzov: "U";
          }
      ]
      var marka = [Audi, Rang, Merc];
      var model = ["4k", "2k", "3k"];
      var cuzov = [Выбрать все]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как пройтись по нашему массиву auto, и выбрать только те объекты, у которых данные совпадают с нашими 2 массивами. Если можно 2 варианты    1) C помощью array.map
2) Цикл for
Ковыряюсь тут, что то совсем не получается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Циклом и фильтром. map тут не поможет, нужен `array.filter`.

```js
var auto = [{
    marka: "BMW",
    model: "4k",
    cuzov: "A"
  },
  {
    marka: "Merc",
    model: "4k",
    cuzov: "B"
  },
  {
    marka: "Audi",
    model: "3k",
    cuzov: "C"
  },
  {
    marka: "Toyota",
    model: "1k",
    cuzov: "D"
  },
  {
    marka: "Lexus",
    model: "2k",
    cuzov: "E"
  },
  {
    marka: "Rang",
    model: "3k",
    cuzov: "F"
  },
  {
    marka: "BMW",
    model: "4k",
    cuzov: "G"
  },
  {
    marka: "BMW",
    model: "2k",
    cuzov: "Y"

  },
  {
    marka: "Audi",
    model: "3k",
    cuzov: "U"
  }
]
var marka = ["Audi", "Rang", "Merc"];
var model = ["4k", "2k", "3k"];

/* фильтром */
var rez1 = auto.filter(x => (marka.includes(x.marka) && model.includes(x.model)));
console.log(rez1);

/* циклом */
var rez2 = [];
for (var auto1 of auto) {
  if (marka.includes(auto1.marka) && model.includes(auto1.model)) {
    rez2.push(auto1);
  }
}
console.log(rez2);
```

Кроме того у вас много ошибок синтаксиса.

1. строки пишутся в кавычках `var string = "str";`
2. элементы массива идут через `,`
3. в конце создания объекта после последнего поля не надо ставить `;`

Comment: А почему filter вот так не работает                                                                       
      `
      var rez1 = auto.filter(function(item){
        if(marka.includes(item.marka) && marka.includes(item.model)){
            return item;
        }
      });

    console.log(rez1);`

Comment: @Sinevik Потому что функция внутри фильтра должна возвращать boolean переменную, которая означает будет ли элемент в результате вывода

Answer (score 2):

```js
var auto = [{
  marka: "BMW",
  model: "4k",
  cuzov: "A"
}, {
  marka: "Merc",
  model: "4k",
  cuzov: "B"
}, {
  marka: "Audi",
  model: "3k",
  cuzov: "C"
}, {
  marka: "Toyota",
  model: "1k",
  cuzov: "D"
}, {
  marka: "Lexus",
  model: "2k",
  cuzov: "E"
}, {
  marka: "Rang",
  model: "3k",
  cuzov: "F"
}, {
  marka: "BMW",
  model: "4k",
  cuzov: "G"
}, {
  marka: "BMW",
  model: "2k",
  cuzov: "Y"
}, {
  marka: "Audi",
  model: "3k",
  cuzov: "U"
}];
var marka = ['Audi', 'Rang', 'Merc'];
var model = ["4k", "2k", "3k"];

// Создаем объекты для быстрого поиска
function createObj(data) {
  var res = {};
  for (var i in data)
    res[data[i]] = 1;
  return res;
}
var markaObj = createObj(marka);
var modelObj = createObj(model);

// Запускаем цикл поиска
var search = [];
for (var i in auto) {
  if (markaObj[auto[i].marka] && modelObj[auto[i].model])
    search.push(auto[i]);
}
console.log(search);
```